# Plotting Objects activity Over Time

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

I have a set of objects, e.g. `{a, b, c, d}` and a list of observations, e.g.:

```
[
    {"day_a" : {a, b}},
    {"day_b" : {a, c}},
    {"day_c" : {b, d}},
    (...)
    {"day_n" : {a}}
]
```

How can I add a plot that will represent this behavior over time?

I think X axis should be time while Y should be the discrete objects but unsure how to create the appropriate graphic representation.

Comment: Imho your data structure is not appropriate for the data you're dealing with. I'd suggest that _you_ convert your data to a dictionary, indexed by the object names, containing a list of booleans expressing if a given object was observed on a particular day.

Comment: OK @gboffi - and how that can be plotted?